# Arm template: cannot configure event hub with application gateway diagnostic settings

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

I have created an Event Hub namespace with event hub and trying to add it into application gateway diagnostic settings but it is not working. (Note: Using nested template)

Here is a working arm template for event-hub:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "hapiEnvironmentName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "eventHubSku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "allowedValues": [ "Basic", "Standard" ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "eventHubNamespaceName": "[concat(parameters('hapiEnvironmentName'), 'GatewayWafLogs')]",
        "eventHubName": "[concat(parameters('hapiEnvironmentName'), 'AppGWafLogs')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "name": "[variables('eventHubNamespaceName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('eventHubSku')]",
                "tier": "[parameters('eventHubSku')]",
                "capacity": 5
            },
            "properties": {
                "isAutoInflateEnabled": true,
                "maximumThroughputUnits": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', variables('eventHubName'))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "messageRetentionInDays": 5,
                "partitionCount": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is a piece of application gateway arm template through which I am trying to add Event hub as diagnostic setting.

```
{
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/providers/diagnosticSettings",
            "name": "[variables('diagnosticSettingsNameForWafLogs')]",
            "properties": {
                "storageAccountId": null,
                "workspaceId": null,
                "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/xxxxxxxxx/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                "eventHubName": "param[('eventhubname')]",
                "metrics": [
                  {
                    "category": "AllMetrics",
                    "enabled": false,
                    "retentionPolicy": {
                      "enabled": false,
                      "days": 0
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog",
                        "enabled": false,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "ApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog",
                        "enabled": false,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', variables('agwafv2Name'))]"
            ]
        }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "NoRegisteredProviderFound",
      "message": "No registered resource provider found for location 'westcentralus' and API version '2017-05-01-preview' for type 'applicationGateways'. The supported api-versions are '2014-12-01-preview, 2015-05-01-preview, 2015-06-15, 2016-03-30, 2016-06-01, 2016-07-01, 2016-08-01, 2016-09-01, 2016-10-01, 2016-11-01, 2016-12-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2018-01-01, 2018-02-01, 2018-03-01, 2018-04-01, 2018-05-01, 2018-06-01, 2018-07-01, 2018-08-01, 2018-10-01, 2018-11-01, 2018-12-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-04-01, 2019-06-01, 2019-07-01, 2019-08-01, 2019-09-01, 2019-11-01, 2019-12-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-04-01, 2020-05-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-08-01, 2020-11-01, 2021-01-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-03-01'. The supported locations are 'westus, eastus, northeurope, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, northcentralus, southcentralus, centralus, eastus2, japaneast, japanwest, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, southindia, westindia, canadacentral, canadaeast, westcentralus, westus2, ukwest, uksouth, koreacentral, koreasouth, francecentral, australiacentral, southafricanorth, uaenorth, switzerlandnorth, germanywestcentral, norwayeast, westus3, jioindiawest'."
    }
  ]
}
```

But the same is working for Log Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Your template use 2017-05-01-preview api version. In the error message states that this API version is not supported. Does it help if you update api to 2021-03-01.